# Bitbucket git reset

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've done this git commands:

```
git reset --hard hash
git push -f
```

All was good locally, I don't see any commits after 'hash' commit. All was good after pushing too, there were no errors, but on Bitbucket main panel of my repository (Overview) last commits still are. And I don't understand it, have I reset remote repository or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your SHA's have not changed so Git doesn't really update the remote on BitBucket.  The history after where you reset still exists, you would be able to do `git pull` and your local repo would get all the later commits.

After doing the `git reset --hard HASH`, do a `git reset HEAD~` (note: this is a soft reset) Then recommit the changes.  This will generate a new SHA for the commit and when you force push your changes, the tree on BitBucket should be updated as you expect.

***WARNING***
This is changing history and if there are others that have pulled from the repo, it will cause trouble.  This should not be a normal workflow for undoing changes on a remote branch, you should use `git revert`.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset` doesn't delete commits; if that's your intent. It resets the current working tree (staged changes to be committed) on your local machine.

Comment: there are no ways to delete commits or clear bitbucket history?

Comment: or reset remote tree to hide commits

Comment: `git revert` can undo a commit specified (not merge commits, though). Outside of that; your best bet would be to start anew.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `git reset --merge <SHA1>` if you want to revert to an older state.

Comment: And starting anew would be deleting your local history and the remote repository and reinitializing the Git repository.