# Need to delete particular commit from bit bucket

Tags: git

I have a commit in my remote branch and I want to delete that commit. Is there any way to do it? I am the only user of the this branch. Below is a screen shot.

[image: Click here to view the screen shot]

Comment: Why not let it in and just undo the changes?

Comment: Exactly.I should do it.Thanks for Quick guide line.

Comment: You can use `git revert <commit>` in your local repo on the command line and then push the result.

Comment: This should be tagged `git`, as it does not have anything to do with `butbucket` or `java`.

Comment: @jurez have you gone through bitbucket by any chance. The screen shot that I have attached is taken from Bitbucket.

Comment: Bitbucket is a hosting website for git repositories. it's only a frontend. If you want to delete commits, you are deleting them by git on your local machine, and that's none of their business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This will reset your working branch, then you need to push it to bitbucket. All you local changes will be  deleted, be careful about using it.

Comment: If you do this it can't be pushed back: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Comment: @Henry can you not force push?

Comment: @puhlen You can, but this is a bit dangerous as it may affect other branches if you are not careful.

Answer (score 0):

Regular git workflows are based on assumption that time always moves forward. Therefore, the standard practice is to not delete commits as you have to rewrite history for that. Instead, you add a new commit to undo changes. There's even the command for that: `git revert`.

*Actually deleting* a commit is a different story, it might be easy or difficult, depending on how many commits, branches and merges are following it. In the simplest case, you have only one branch, no merges and no changes that depend on commit you are deleting. In other cases, you might get a lot of conflicts, or might even choose to sacrifice the entire history after that commit. I don't know what your case is.

In the simplest case, assuming your current branch is `master` and you want to delete commit `C`, and your history from `C` to `master` is a linear sequence of commits, and `D` is the commit following `C`, you can do something like this:

```
git checkout -b temp C~1
git cherry-pick D..master
git branch -f master
git checkout master
git branch -D temp
git push -f origin master
```

**Beware** though, that this will break any repositories other than yours, and they will have to redo their work. Not recommended unless you work alone.

Second note: if you're trying to delete sensitive information (e.g. passwords committed by accident), this might not actually erase data due to the way git works internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by dropping the commit and force pushing the updated branch to your remote. Note: careful if other persons have checkout the branch.

Supposing your history is like the following and you want to delete commit 200:

> commit 300 commit 200 commit 100

Do the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Now, delete the line of commit 200.

Save the file, and then force push the branch to the remote:

```
git push -f origin <branch_name>
```

This work perfectly for me.
Reference:[Completely remove commit from Bitbucket history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874104/completely-remove-commit-from-bitbucket-history)